# Stroke created of shape or image

Tags: javafx-2

I remember in Java2D I could create a stroke which is flow of images or complex shape.

I want to know is this also possible in JavaFX. if yes, How?

How can I create a stroke like the image?

[image: stroke]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [stroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setStroke%28javafx.scene.paint.Paint%29) of your shape to an [ImagePattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html) and you will have uniformally patterned strokes.

Looking at the picture in your question, the pattern appears to be distorted (squeezed on the inner curve and stretched on the outer curve).

A [DisplacementMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/DisplacementMap.html) in conjunction with the above patterning technique may perhaps be used to produce similar distortion.